# script to move files from one directory to another 

Tags: bash, shell, mv, dovecot

I have successfully changed my mail imap agent from dovecot to courier-imap, for some required features, how ever i am facing a problem during the maildrop/seive directory structure where i need to move 10000 mailboxes to correct directory structure,

so what i need is a script that will convert to move  like this

mv /var/vmail/[ domain ]/[ username ]/Maildir/* /var/vmail/[ domain ]/[ username ]/

and i dont want to run this command 10000 times, its troublesome, could you help with this,

thank you

Comment: can you give a concrete example where domain and username have meaningful values?

Comment: Thank you 

mv /var/vmail/skuliweb.com/test/Maildir/* /var/vmail/skuliweb.com/test

mv /var/vmail/skuliweb.com/test2/Maildir/* /var/vmail/skuliweb.com/test2

Comment: ok, so you will probably have to generate a list of all domains + all users - a file where on each line you have: domain<delimiter>user; Than use a loop, where for each line of the generated file, you execute the above command with the appropriate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
for dir in /var/vmail/*/*
do
  mv "$dir"/Mail/* "$dir"
done
```